# Why is the following definition correct for a first-order homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Definition**

$\frac{dy}{dx}+a(x)y=0$

**Contradiction**

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}$ is impossible to express as the definition says.

Comment: what is $a(x)$   here?

Comment: Any function of x. Is it not clear?

Comment: It’s not clear what the question is. You can define a term to be whatever you want it to be, but it helps to use the term as used by everybody else, just to make talking with people easier. There is no “contradiction” in your line - the differential equation there does not qualify under the usual definition. The real question is, why do you want to redefine the term to include the “contradiction” equation? Do the techniques used for solving homogeneous equations also apply to your “contradiction” example?

Comment: Also, $M(x,y),N(x,y)$ are not a homogeneous diff eq. An equation has to have an $=$ sign, would be very weird if there were any differentials in $M(x,y).$

Comment: I don't understand, Thomas, what you are explaining to me. You say that the differential equation there does not qualify under the usual definition: why is this not a contradiction? The definition should work for all the homogeneous differential equations.

Answer (score 2):

The word "homogeneous" is in use in two different ways for differential equations,

- the homogeneous version $L[y]=0$ of a linear differential equation $L[y]=r$, which can be thought of a being homogeneous of degree 1 in $y$ (and $y$ alone), meaning that $L[ay]=aL[y]=0$, $a\ne 0$ a scalar;
- and first-order DE $y'=f(x,y)$ that have a right side $f(x,y)$ that is homogeneous of degree $0$ over all variables, $f(ax,ay)=a^0f(x,y)=f(1,y/x)$. The function $f$ can here be arbitrarily non-linear.

You gave an example for each variant, showing that indeed they are incompatible.

Answer (score -1):

No,  I mean in your problem $$\frac{dy}{dx}+a(x)y=0
\\\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}
\\\frac{dy}{dx}-\underbrace{\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy^2}}_{a(x)}y=0\\
\to \frac{x^2+y^2}{xy^2}=a(x,y)$$and ,it's not only function of $x$. so  there is no contradiction.Is there ?

Comment: Why are yo telling that there is no contradiction? There is a contradiction. You can't express the function "a" only in terms of "x".

Comment: If I define “odd number,” and you give me the example $4$ which is not an odd number, it isn’t a “contradiction.”  It just means $4$ is not an odd number. 
@SergioDuránVega

Comment: There are plenty of diff. equations which are not homogeneous. It is exactly why we define the term. @SergioDuránVega

Comment: I see the following: (1) we have a definition for diff. homogeneous equations ($\frac{dy}{dx}+a(x)y=0$), (2) we have the diff. homogeneous equation $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}=0$ (3) which it can't be expressed as the definition says. Therefore, we have a contradiction. Maybe, you are telling me that the definition is for a particular set of diff. homogeneous equations, but not for all. In this case, my example is not a contradiction, it's a wrong example for the definition. Is it correct ?